# Unpreventable keyboard shortcuts in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, browser, preventdefault

as the title suggests, I was wondering - what keyboard shortcuts cannot be prevented with javascript in modern browsers? Is this browser-dependent or even system-dependent?

So far, I've got `Ctrl+N`,`Ctrl+Shift+N`,`Ctrl+T`,`Ctrl+Shift+T`,`Ctrl+W`,`Ctrl+Shift+W`, all from Google Chrome. Then there's the standard windows shortcuts with the windows key like the windows key itself, `winkey+R`, `winkey+S`, etc., but also `Ctrl+Shift+Escape`. Is there any way to know what keyboard shortcuts will lead to something javascript can't prevent?

I suppose my question boils down to: if `event` is a keyboard event, then what does `event.preventDefault();` actually prevent?

**EDIT**
Let's make a list here:

- `Ctrl+N`
- `Ctrl+Shift+N`
- `Ctrl+T`
- `Ctrl+Shift+N`
- `Ctrl+W`
- `Ctrl+Shift+W`
- `winkey + anything?`
- `Ctrl+Shift+Escape`
- `Ctrl+Alt-Delete` (added by Psi)
- `Alt+F4`
- `Escape` and `F11` (for fullscreen) (added by zer00ne)

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+Del` will surely not be preventable as well ^^

Comment: Indeed it won't, just like `alt+F4`, and there probably are a lot more of them

Comment: I guess you won't find a complete list, the only thing you can do is test them all. And if you did, post it in the docs :D

Comment: That's going to be a lot of testing if it's both browser- and system-dependent; surely there must be an easier way, right?

Comment: Maybe you can create a javascript catching all keyboard events and an external script (such as a vb-script) firing keystrokes to the browser. I don't know, however, if you can detect whether it is preventable.

Comment: Put F11 and Esc for exiting full screen on that list of unpreventable events

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `capturing` phase of events to handle and prevent it from default behaviour.

BUT! You cant override CTRL+R, CTRL+W or CMD events in safari.

Better way to prevent user for refreshing page is
     window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {}

For example

```
function preventFn(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === YOU_KEY_CODE && event.metaKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', preventFn, true); // true means use capture phase of event
```

for example you can use high level library for shortcuts management

[hotkeys](https://github.com/jaywcjlove/hotkeys) - powerfull

[stack-shortcuts](https://github.com/BusinessDuck/stack-shortcuts) - small and easy

p.s. instead of `event.metaKey` use what do you need. docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey)